# Count duplicate digits with regular expressions / regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a way to count repetitive digit pairs in a stdin input with regular expressions in Python. With my regex

```
(\d+)(?=\d*\1)
```

I am able to extract repetitive digits, but not only pairs and not the number of repetitions:

```
1122332200 -> ['1', '22', '3', '2', '0']
```

Here I should have result 2, as there are two occurrences of 22.
Do you have any suggestions how to count the pairs with regex?

Thx, reiti

Comment: You can use `(\d)\1+` and then count the length of the match.

Comment: Use @Thefourthbird's regex and iterate all matches while putting the match into a dictionary using the match as the key and keep incrementing a counter as the value.

Comment: When saying "pairs" do you mean that in `1100022000` you do not expect any match/result?

Comment: Please add more details to the question to clarify, if you still need an answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers so far. In 1100022000 I would expect 2 pairs of 00 (only pairs and no overlapping digits). Example: Result for 112222 is 2 (as there are two pairs of 2)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link for an example:

https://regex101.com/r/PlQYrT/1

Your question isn't entirely clear about how you wish to match pairs. "Pairs" to me would mean exactly 2 repeating digits, so a number like 10222 would match 2 once, but 102222 would match 2 twice. The regex I provided uses a range quantifier `{1,2}` to optionally match an odd number of characters, and the non-greedy qualifier `?` so it still lets a second pair match if there are four.

Putting it together `(\d)\1{1,2}?` matches up to 3 of the same digit, but if there is a fourth repetition of that digit, the non-greedy `?` will allow it to match that digit twice.

Please add more lines to my example to explore and test on your own, or change the range quantifier to `{1,}` for one or more (same as `+`) to match all repeating digits, regardless of quantity.